Does the constant term of the minimal polynomial of an algebraic function also have no univariate factor if the algebraic function has none?
Each algebraic function is defined by an irreducible algebraic equation or its minimal polynomial, respectively.
My question is:
Let

${}^{-}$ denote the algebraic closure,
$\pmb{n\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}}$,
$x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be complex variables,
$\pmb{A\colon (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto A(x_1,...,x_n)}$ be a non-constant $\pmb{n}$-ary algebraic function so that $\pmb{A(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}$ doesn't have, for all $\pmb{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}$, a factor $\pmb{a\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}(x_i)}\setminus\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ (a univariate factor).

Does this mean that the constant term of the minimal polynomial of $\pmb{A(x_1,...,x_n)}$ also has no univariate factor?  If yes, how can we prove this?
This applies at least if $A(x_1,...,x_n)$ is rational in $x_1,...,x_n$, but I'm asking for algebraic irrational $A$.
Is there a general systematic and complete method or algorithm to determine the minimal polynomial of an arbitrary algebraic number?
Is there a general systematic and complete method or algorithm to determine the minimal polynomial of an arbitrary algebraic function of more than one variable?
I need this for a proof of unsolvability of some kinds of equations of transcendental functions, e.g. elementary functions.
I'm familiar with elementary algebra, but the answers can also be in the language of abstract algebra.
